# Reaccess the same UIViewController across the app

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let says that I have an UITabBarController based app, and for example it got 2 tabs, VC A and B. I have VC X that will be used accross the app, no matter it will be pushed or modally presented. VC A is a pageViewController that will show VC X and VC C, VC B is a UITableView and one of the cell if pressed will go to VC X (pushed). VC X state needs to be preserved as if I open it on VC A then select something, it will show the same state when I open it via VC B. What I have done so far is to make VC X as a Singleton and it will be used everywhere.

```
static XViewController *sharedInstance;

+ (XViewController *)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
       dispatch_once(&once, ^{
         sharedInstance= [[XViewController alloc]init];
     });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Calling VCX :

```
XViewController *viewController = [XViewController sharedInstance];
```

The problem is when I open VC X from VC A, then open VC X from VC B, go back and open VC X from VC A, the view will be blank and when I choose VC C and choose VC X it will show again.

So the question is what approach should I take to fix this problem or to achieve what i want? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution, It seems my approach already working and correct, but I missed something when try to show the VC X after being pushed from VC B. because on VC A I used PageViewController, then on its root viewWillAppear, I need to re-set the viewController being displayed.

```
[self.pageController setViewControllers:@[self.viewControllers[self.lastIndex]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
```

and thats it, all work as intended. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your singleton approach should work.  In VC A, are you somehow re-initializing VC X whereas in VC B you're getting a reference and using the existing VC X?

If you don't want to use a singleton, you could instead have VC X know how to rebuild itself by having the controller save any needed values on the controller's `viewDidDisappear()` and/or `deinit`

Comment: Hi, in VC A i am not re-initializing. Well it will be initialized if I open X from VC A for the first time. I am trying to avoid saving values if possible as the purpose is clear, to reuse the viewController.